# How to set the primary video card in Windows 8.1?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, windows-8.1

I have a laptop running bare Windows 8.1 installed from scratch, no OEM crapware. The laptop has to video cards:

- AMD Radeon HD 8500M Series
- Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000

Both cards use the stock drivers installed by Windows 8.1. How do I set the primary card to HD Graphics?

Disabling AMD Radeon in Device Manager kills the brightness control. If however I keep it enabled, the laptop fan runs crazy even when it's idle (no graphics tasks).